# How to pass array to thread in java?

Tags: java

i want to pass array to thread and display in it.but i do not know how i can pass array to thread?
i tried same like passing array to function but it does not work.
i have two thread , and in both thread i will print the array . here is my thread 1

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread {

    public void run()
        {
            //here i will print

        }

    }
```

how i can pass thread and how it will use in main? like thread.start(array?);
please help.

Comment: Why don't you pass it to the constructor which saves it in a field and uses it in its methods?

Comment: Side recommendation: Don't extend Thread. Instead implement Runnable.

Comment: @umer If any of the answers is the right one for you, please mark it as accepted, so that other users know that this is not an open issue anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a constructor and an instance field:

```
public class Thread1 extends Thread {

    private int[] array;

    public Thread1(int[] array)
    {
        this.array=array;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        // use array here.

    }

}
```

And to call it:

```
Thread1 th=new Thread1(array);
th.start();
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but keep in mind that if one of the threads makes changes to the (same) array it is not guaranteed to be visible to the other thread as you do not perform any synchronization on the array later on. Read more about this in the [Java Specification Request #133](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/jsr133.pdf) which introduces the current Java Memory Model (JMM).

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock You're right. I wrote this code assuming that `array` is only used as input to the thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Thread1 extends Thread{
    int[] array;
  Thread1(int[] myarray){

    this.array = myarray;

  }


}
```

Like this pass to construcctor

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a blocking queue that the thread will check periodically. A blocking queue allow you to modify the array during thread execution. It always a good practice when working with threaded applications is to use an datatype that only permit one thread access at a time.

```
private LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer[]> arrayQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Integer[]>();
...
public class Thread1 extends Thread {

    public void run()
        {
            int[] arrayPoll = arrayQueue.poll();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

#Person.Java#

```
import java.util.Objects;

public class Person implements Comparable {
String firstName;
String lastName;
Integer age;
Integer DOBYear;

public Person(String firstName, String lastName, Integer age, Integer DOBYear) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.age = age;
    this.DOBYear = DOBYear;
}

public String getFirstName() {
    return firstName;
}

public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
}

public String getLastName() {
    return lastName;
}

public void setLastName(String lastName) {
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Integer getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(Integer age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public Integer getDOBYear() {
    return DOBYear;
}

public void setDOBYear(Integer DOBYear) {
    this.DOBYear = DOBYear;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Person person = (Person) o;
    return Objects.equals(firstName, person.firstName) && Objects.equals(lastName, person.lastName) && Objects.equals(age, person.age) && Objects.equals(DOBYear, person.DOBYear);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(firstName, lastName, age, DOBYear);
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    Person p = (Person) o;
    return p.getAge() > this.getAge() ? -1: p.getAge() == this.getAge() ? 0 : 1;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Person{" +
            "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", age=" + age +
            ", DOBYear=" + DOBYear +
            '}';
}
```

}

#PersonNameComparator.Java#

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class PersonNameComparator implements Comparator<Person> {


@Override
public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
    return o1.getFirstName().compareTo(o2.getFirstName());
}
```

}

#PersonTest.java#

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;

public class PersonTest {
public static void main(String args[]){

    System.out.println("Hello World");
    Person p1 = new Person("Umesh","Bhutada",31,1991);
    Person p2 = new Person("Deepali","Baheti",29,1992);
    Person p3 = new Person("Romeet","Zanwar",5,2017);

    ArrayList<Person> arr1 = new ArrayList<Person>( Arrays.asList(p1,p2,p3));
    ArrayList<Person> arr2 = new ArrayList<Person>( Arrays.asList(p2,p1,p3));
    ArrayList<Person> arr3 = new ArrayList<Person>( Arrays.asList(p3,p2,p1));

    Runnable r1 = () -> {
        System.out.println("Begin t1");
        arr1.forEach(person -> {System.out.println("t1 begin : "+ person);});
        Collections.sort(arr1, new PersonNameComparator());
        arr1.forEach(person -> {System.out.println("t1 sorted : "+ person);});
        System.out.println("end t1");
    };
    Runnable r2 = () -> {
        System.out.println("Begin t2");
        arr2.forEach(person -> {System.out.println("t2 begin : "+ person);});
        Collections.sort(arr2, new PersonNameComparator());
        arr2.forEach(person -> {System.out.println("t2 sorted : "+ person);});
        System.out.println("end t2");
    };

    Runnable r3 = () -> {
        System.out.println("Begin t3");
        arr3.forEach(person -> {System.out.println("t3 begin : "+ person);});
        Collections.sort(arr3, new PersonNameComparator());
        arr3.forEach(person -> {System.out.println("t3 sorted : "+ person);});
        System.out.println("end t3");
    };

    Thread t1 = new Thread(r1);
    t1.setName("PersonTest1");
    System.out.println("started t1");
    t1.start();
    System.out.println("end of  t1");


    Thread t2 = new Thread(r2);
    t2.setName("PersonTest2");
    System.out.println("Started t2");
    t2.start();
    System.out.println("end of  t2");

    Thread t3 = new Thread(r3);
    t3.setName("PersonTest3");
    System.out.println("Started t3");
    t3.start();
    System.out.println("Ended t3");

}
```

}

#Output#

```
Hello World
started t1
end of  t1
Started t2
end of  t2
Started t3
Ended t3
Begin t1
Begin t2
Begin t3
t2 begin : Person{firstName='Deepali', lastName='Baheti', age=29, DOBYear=1992}
t2 begin : Person{firstName='Umesh', lastName='Bhutada', age=31, DOBYear=1991}
t2 begin : Person{firstName='Romeet', lastName='Zanwar', age=5, DOBYear=2017}
t2 sorted : Person{firstName='Deepali', lastName='Baheti', age=29, DOBYear=1992}
t2 sorted : Person{firstName='Romeet', lastName='Zanwar', age=5, DOBYear=2017}
t2 sorted : Person{firstName='Umesh', lastName='Bhutada', age=31, DOBYear=1991}
end t2
t3 begin : Person{firstName='Romeet', lastName='Zanwar', age=5, DOBYear=2017}
t3 begin : Person{firstName='Deepali', lastName='Baheti', age=29, DOBYear=1992}
t3 begin : Person{firstName='Umesh', lastName='Bhutada', age=31, DOBYear=1991}
t3 sorted : Person{firstName='Deepali', lastName='Baheti', age=29, DOBYear=1992}
t3 sorted : Person{firstName='Romeet', lastName='Zanwar', age=5, DOBYear=2017}
t3 sorted : Person{firstName='Umesh', lastName='Bhutada', age=31, DOBYear=1991}
end t3
t1 begin : Person{firstName='Umesh', lastName='Bhutada', age=31, DOBYear=1991}
t1 begin : Person{firstName='Deepali', lastName='Baheti', age=29, DOBYear=1992}
t1 begin : Person{firstName='Romeet', lastName='Zanwar', age=5, DOBYear=2017}
t1 sorted : Person{firstName='Deepali', lastName='Baheti', age=29, DOBYear=1992}
t1 sorted : Person{firstName='Romeet', lastName='Zanwar', age=5, DOBYear=2017}
t1 sorted : Person{firstName='Umesh', lastName='Bhutada', age=31, DOBYear=1991}
end t1
```